# Selenium searches for the xpath to be clicked in the background and gives error. Actual element to be clicked is in a box

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Selenium searches for the xpath to be clicked in the background and gives error. Actual element to be clicked is in a box. Please see the image. I want to click on interface (22) tab. But the script throws the following error.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/taut_mcp/communication/mcp_web.py", line 193, in <module>
    mcp.interface_data_get()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\taut_mcp\command\mcp_gui.py", line 128, in interface_data_get
    self.force_click('//div[4]/div/div')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\taut_selenium\taut_selenium.py", line 844, in force_click
    found_element = self.element_find(element)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\taut_selenium\taut_selenium.py", line 296, in element_find
    found_element = self.any_condition_wait(element, real_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\taut_selenium\taut_selenium.py", line 820, in any_condition_wait
    found_element = this_wait.until(ec((by_id, this_selector)))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/uvijayac/appdata/local/temp/tmp3wnxmc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/uvijayac/appdata/local/temp/tmp3wnxmc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/uvijayac/appdata/local/temp/tmp3wnxmc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/uvijayac/appdata/local/temp/tmp3wnxmc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/uvijayac/appdata/local/temp/tmp3wnxmc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: Seems that your element is under `iframe`. are u searching the `xpath` after switching into the frame

Comment: no.. i am new to selenium. can you please help me how to switch to frame